# Cannot capture python stdout inside Docker container using child_process in node

Tags: python, node.js, docker, stdout

I have a **server.js** file that uses **child_process** to call a **python** file:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
path = require('path');
fs = require('fs')

app.get('/call_script', function(req, res) {

  function_choice = req.query.function_choice   
  args_choice = req.query.args_choice

  // call python scripts
  var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
  var process = spawn("python",["test.py", function_args]);

  process.stdout.on("data", function (data){
    from_python = data.toString("utf8");
    from_python = from_python.replace(/\n/g, " ").replace(/\\n/g, " "); 
    res.json({
       "answer" : from_python
    })

});
```

The python file:

```
function_args = sys.argv[1]

# ..... retrieve function and arguments from function_args

result = locals()[function_choice](*arr_n)

print(result)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

If I run node server.js in the terminal it runs the file and **works perfectly**. I can call the express endpoint using a URL with Ajax. The python file gets called and returns the output correctly. No problems.

If I now place server.js into a **Docker** container the output from python is *not returned*. There are no errors or crashes, just nothing. The Ajax call just hangs and returns nothing.

The Dockerfile and package.json contain all necessary commands and dependencies. I can run the container with everything working EXCEPT the python output.

I know there are [issues](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/453) with **Docker/node and stdout** but I have not been able to get the python output to come outside the container.

If I put **console.log** **inside process.stdout.on** the **terminal** and Docker **logs** show nothing.

Is it something to do with buffering or flushing?

EDIT

It seems it has something to do with modules not being made available. For example, matplotlib is not found, yet it installs during docker build.

Here is my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:9

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python3 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8899
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

And this is my **requirements.txt**

```
matplotlib
```

EDIT2

```
pip3 show matplotlib
```

Name: matplotlib

Version: 2.1.1

Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages

Requires: numpy, six, python-dateutil, pytz, cycler, pyparsing

```
import sys, for p in sys.path: print(p)
```

/usr/lib/python3.4

/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu

/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

Comment: Go inside the container and run the python code.  ```docker exec -it <container id> bash```.  Also, did you inspect stderr?

Comment: This is how you enter the container correct? Is there a command you want me to run once inside?

Comment: That is how to get inside the running container.  I would simulate whatever you are spawning in node.  Basically, ```python test.py``` and whatever other arguments you are passing.

Comment: I am getting ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot.  But I can see that matplotlib is installed during Docker build.

Comment: Might help to see your requirements.txt file and probably your Dockerfile too.  There must be some disconnect between where matplotlib was installed and where python thinks it is.

Comment: Added Dockerfile and requirements.txt to end of question.

Comment: Ugh.  I would go back into the container, and run ```pip3 show matplotlib```.  Then run python3, ```import sys```, ```for p in sys.path:    print(p)```.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** add the `-u` option when you call the python executable.

> If I put console.log inside process.stdout.on the terminal and Docker logs show nothing.
> Is it something to do with buffering or flushing?

Yes, during my testing, it seems that when you use the default node Docker image there are some issues with the buffering of the stdout file, as you have already seen in the linked issue https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/453.

From the python documentation this is documented in the `sys.stdout` section:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout

> When interactive, stdout and stderr streams are line-buffered. Otherwise, they are block-buffered like regular text files. You can override this value with the -u command-line option.

I solved this issue by calling the python executable with the **additional `-u` option** which forces the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered (https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u)

In your case, the following would probably fix your issue:

```
var process = spawn("python", ["-u", "test.py", function_args]);
```